# How to build custom toolchain in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, dh-make

We are planning to migrate to Ubuntu 16.0.4LTS as a development distribution.
Currently, we are using old Suse distribution.

One of the tasks in this migration is to build our custom toolchain on Ubuntu.
Currently we have RPMs of various packages that make our toolchain.We are also doing binary repeatibility. We are following something similar to `LFS (Linux From Scratch)` method to build our toolchain.

Now, in order to build these packages on Ubuntu in `.deb` format I started reading maintainer's guide at https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.en.html

Seems that I need `dh-make` and `debhelper` packages before I can create `.deb` packages of various libraries/tools comprising our toolchain.

What I am asking here is whether the method that I am going to follow is correct or not:

```
Pass 1: ( Exactly as Pass 1 of LFS-Linux From Scratch )
I will build - Binutils,GCC,Linux Headers,Glibc,Libstdc++
```

then in pass 2:

```
Pass 2: ( Exactly as Pass 2 of LFS-Linux From Scratch )
I will build - Binutils,GCC,Tcl-core,Expect,DejaGNU,Check,Ncurses,
Bash,Bzip2,Coreutils,Diffutils,File,Findutils,Gawk,Gettext,Grep,
Gzip,M4,Make,Patch,Perl,Sed,Tar,Texinfo,Util-linux,Xz
```

Once Pass2 is done, I will `chroot` into the directory where I installed utilities from Pass1 and Pass2.
And then will begin the compilation of `gcc`

But for creating `.deb` packages of my toolchain, I think I need to compile `dh-make` and `debhelper` packages before I can create the `gcc.deb` package. Is that right ?

Once I have `gcc`,`dh-make` and `debhelper` packages, I should be good to create other packages in the toolchain.

Let me know what you guys think.